# How to include Capybara into module in Cucumber project

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I defined a module:

```
module Support
  include Capybara::DSL

  def self.do_something
    click_link 'Questions'
  end
end
```

It's situated at features/support/support.rb

My env.rb:

```
require 'capybara'
require 'cucumber'
require 'capybara/cucumber'

Capybara.app_host = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
```

I invoke function of module in steps.rb:

```
Support::do_something
```

And I have exception:

```
undefined method `click_link' for Support:Module (NoMethodError)
```

How can I make Capybara available in Support module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Capybara should be `extend`-ed, not `include`-ed:

```
module Support
  extend Capybara::DSL

  def self.do_something
    click_link 'Questions'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
module SupportModule
    class Support
        include Capybara::DSL

        def do_something
            click_link 'Questions'
        end
    end
end

s = SupportModule::Support.new
s.do_something
```

http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/DSL