# Adding module to Capybara and Cucumber tests

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber, capybara

I would like to add a module that contains methods to execute Javascript, within our tests written in Capybara and Cucumber.

I have added a module within the features/support/ directory called ShadowDOM.rb

```
module Shadow

def self.click(shadow_elm, target, index=0)

puts 'hell0'
 execute_script("
                  var shadow_elm = '#{shadow_elm}';
                  var target = '#{target}';
                  var index = '#{index}';

                  window.qa.tap(document.querySelectorAll( shadow_elm+ ' /deep/ ' +target)[index]);
                ")
  end

end
```

When I run the Cucumber test I can see that it prints out 'hell0' to the console. So Shadow.click() is working. However I get the error NoMethodError: undefined method `execute_script' for Shadow:Module
which leads me to believe that it is not recognizing Capybara functions within the module. How do I link the module to Capybara?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include Capybara into module in Cucumber project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057532/how-to-include-capybara-into-module-in-cucumber-project). As mentioned in the other question, you can extend your module with the Capybara::DSL.

Comment: I added the extend Capybara::DSL and it now recognizes execute_script but I get a undefined method `expect' for Shadow:Module error

Comment: I do not believe that `expect` comes from Capybara. You likely need to include something like the RSpec::Expectations. However, without seeing all of the code, it is hard to tell what you need to do.